# Why can't I get a javascript caused by hoisting

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I am trying to get my head around hoisting, I'm going through a codeschool tutorial (es2015), and I can't seem to get their code to work. (they display just parts of the code, so what follows is my version)

```
function _myfunc(callback){
  callback();
}

function display(names){
  for(var i in names){
    _mfunc(function(){
      console.log(names[i]);
    });
  }
}
display(["Sam", "Tyler", "brook", "alex"]);
```

Apparently `var i` is hoisted above the `for` loop, and what I should see in the console is `alex` consoled four times. But I see all four names consoled. (Then I'm meant to use `let` rather than `var`to get it working, but I need to brake it before getting it to work)

Can you help me fix/brake the code so I can see hoisting working against the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be one way to break your code:

```
function display(names){
  for(var i in names){
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(names[i]);
    }, 0);
  }
}
display(["Sam", "Tyler", "brook", "alex"]);
```

What happens here is that callback functions passed to the `setTimeout` are scheduled to run *after* the loop completes. And as soon as they all capture the `i` variable, which has the value `3` in the end of the loop - they all output the same.

PS: I would recommend to not use `for-in` to iterate over arrays, but use normal `for` with a counter instead.

Comment: Thanks. By "use normal for which a counter", you mean `for (var i = name.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: @relidon almost - just a normal *increasing* counter: `for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++)`